# MATLAB: Create a Sparse matrix from Compressed Column storage

Tags: matlab

I have a C++ program which spits out the various arrays that are used to represent a matrix in compressed column storage format.

For instance I have the following data:

```
column_pointer = [ 0,3,6,8, 10]
row_index = [0,1,3,1,2,3,0,2,1,3]
values = [4.0, 3.0, 3.0, 2.7, 1.8, 0.3, 3.2, 3.0, 0.1, 1.0]
```

I want to create a sparse matrix from this values in MATLAB. But the only way i found was to use `spconvert` and load it from triplet form.

Any other way to do it?

Comment: @rahnema1 I changed it and I also gave my answer after taking a look at your code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`sparse`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sparse.html) can be used to create sparse matrix from indexes of rows and columns and values. You need to add one to indexes to get `1`-based indexes and use `diff` and `repelem` to convert `column_pointer` to `col_index`.

```
row_index = row_index + 1;
col_index = repelem(1:numel(column_pointer)-1,diff(column_pointer));
result = sparse(row_index, col_index, values);
```

Comment: I am facing some issue when 

`column_pointer = [0, 1, 4, 8]
row_index = [2 0 1 3 0 1 2 3 ]
values = [2 1 3 2 4 1 1 2 ]`

Answer (score 0):

I took inspiration from @rahnema1 and was able to code it up.

```
        a = column_pointer+1;
        a = diff(a);
        Ci =row_index+1;
        Cx = values

        count = 1;
        Cp = [];
        for i = 1:length(a)
           Cp = [Cp count * ones(1,a(i))];
           count = count+1;
        end

        M = sparse(Ci, Cp, Cx);
```

Comment: Always preallocate instead of continuously changing the size of arrays. [*Read why here*](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/preallocating-arrays.html). Using `i` as a variable name is also not a good idea